# MX Ergo trackball mouse battery draining - How to tell what driver Ubuntu is using?

Tags: drivers, 22.04, bluetooth, mouse, logitech

There's a known problem where an MX Ergo Trackball mouse drains it's battery when the Logitech Options+ software is installed (Windows only software). I went back to the standard Options software, and the problem went away.  I've started using a second linux PC, on my desk next to the Windows PC (using this mouse for both), and the linux PC is draining the mouses battery. I confirmed this by using a different mouse on my Windows PC for a couple weeks. The linux machine drains the battery within a week, while I normally charge it every 2-3 months.

I installed hardinfo to try to find out what driver the trackball is using. It only reports a "connected to" address for the trackball, which I assume is the Bluetooth address. hardinfo doesn't have a Bluetooth category. I'm trying to find out what mouse driver is being used, and whether an alternative is available. The trackball works perfectly, and the linux machine reports when the battery gets low. I'm using Bluetooth, not the unifying USB receiver.

Comment: It uses a generic bluetooth Human Input Device driver. Linux doesn't really handle device drivers in the Windows way - generally the kernel supports things to varying degrees. This may be everything between a generic support and supports for all nooks and crannies of the device.

Comment: If you have inxi installed, it might give you more info. inxi -v7azy 'or you may try. modinfo bluetooth

Comment: Is it a rechargeable mouse? Is there anything around that can interfere or block, forcing the mouse to boost the signal? Dirty lens, black desktop, wifi router, microwave, plastic or mirrors objects in the way, lead, etc. Like vidarlo said above, the driver is not the likely problem. One thing I have done in past is move the mouse dongle to a different usb port. Even the desk or keyboard can block the signal.

Comment: @Nishnabe The mouse is rechargeable, and it's using Bluetooth. The mouse is on a wood desktop, with the computer on a shelf just under it. Less than 2 feet away. There's a single 1/2" piece of wood between them. I wouldn't think it was the driver either, except the wrong windows program drains the battery, as described in the post.

Comment: This is odd, a program draining a mouse battery? There is a terminal command program htop that will show all sources being used, it may show a rogue program draining the mouse battery.